# SIG_IGN signal handler in c , how to terminate the program?

Tags: c

I understand that using sig_ign like `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);` will cause the program to ignore Signal. So entering `CTRL-C` will not terminate the program. So, how do we actually terminate these kind of program(assuming that the program has an infinite loop in it).

Comment: You can't change the signal disposition for `SIGKILL` (and `SIGSTOP`). man 7 signal: *The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.*

Comment: ...but you might want to try `SIGTERM` first.

Comment: @user414777 The default for `SIGQUIT` is ```^\```, not `^Q`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Indeed, sorry. `Control-Backslash` => `SIGQUIT` may work instead of `Control-C`. Notice however that `SIGQUIT` *may* also cause the program to create a coredump (though that's no longer the default on most Linux distros).